# running intellij project show wrong page and url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a problem to show my spring projects via `Intellij` and `tomcat`. when I run  the project in the browser I enter `localhost:8080`. then after enter it converted to `localhost:8080/login` and show another homepage of another project! My project is with spring mvc.

I cleared cache the chrom and firefox browser. The project's domains are different too. (I choosed from spring.io/initializer)

How can I solve the problem? Thanks for your help